# Why dev console stops my request showing CORS error while other rest tools aren't

Tags: api, nginx, cors, fetch-api

I don't understand why when I open a web browser and call some API url using fetch API (in dev console) I get CORS error, but when I do it using IntelliJ everything is fine.

The API server has following headers in its NGINX config

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
```

Comment: What does the browser error say?

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to add method: "no-cors" in fetch api call. I didn't really read the whole error message and I catched only a big "CORS" word

Answer (score -1):

I just had to add

```
mode: "no-cors"
```

to fetchApi call

Comment: Not a great answer as in your question you state to allow the methods of `PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS` which would still fail with the `no-cors` mode.